# Ionic controllers alias not working when using sidebar

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, state, angular-ui-router

I have an app built using ionic framework, I follow the instructions on ionicframework learn page and now I am using the native sidemenu. The problem is, I can't use controller alias. Here is a snipet of my app.js with the route config:

```
 angular.module('checklist-atendimento', [
  'ionic',
  'oc.lazyLoad',
  'ngStorage',
  'ngCordova',
  'ngMask'
])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/atendimento/1');

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('TratamentoDeErrosService');

    $stateProvider
      .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/app',
        views: {
          'conteudo': {
            templateUrl: 'app/templates/menu.html'
          }
        }
      })
      .state('app.inicio', {
        url: '/inicio',
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'app/views/inicio.html',
            controller: 'InicioController',
          }
        }
      })
      .state('app.atendimento', {
        url: '/atendimento/:codMenu',
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'app/views/atendimento.html',
            controller: 'AtendimentoController',
            controllerAs: 'atendimentoCrl'
          }
        }
      })
  });
```

As you can see, I have 2 states, one without controllerAs (InicioController) and the other using controllerAs (AtendimentoController).

In controller I put

```
$scope.test ="TEST!!!"
```

and in the view I put

```
<b>{{atendimentoCtrl.test}}<b>
```

Nothing happens, if I use just {{test}}, but the text is shown.
Anyone knows how to do it ?

***EDIT:***

**HERE there is a example of what a talking about:**

http://plnkr.co/ohL5HE

Look inside ItemCtrl and inside index.html, on item.html.
I tried use an alias to controller but it don't works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
$scope.test ="TEST!!!"
```

to:

```
this.test ="TEST!!!"
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is just a typo... This is a controller state

```
 .state('app.atendimento', {
    url: '/atendimento/:codMenu',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/atendimento.html',
        controller: 'AtendimentoController',
        controllerAs: 'atendimentoCrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

where we can see **`'atendimentoCrl'`**. And here is a view statement

```
<b>{{atendimentoCtrl.test}}<b>
```

where we can see **`atendimentoCtrl`** *(compare **`Ctrl`** suffix and **`Crl`** above)*

So, there is missing **`t`** in the `controllerAs`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. In my project the html is correct. This is not the problem.

Comment: Wel, this should simply work. If you can create some plunker and reproduce the issue *(because here you simply provided just "not relevant" info)* - I can assist, if you want...

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I provide an example that reproduce my problem, to improve question to help you to understand.